# Hide keyboard screen in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I would like to know how to hide the keyboard screen when switching fragments in an activity.

I have an activity that launches a fragment. This fragment has a TextInputEditText view where I can type in some text, automatically the keyboard shows up when the TextInputEditText view is selected. When I am done typing in the text, I click on a programmed "Button" that takes me to another fragment. Unfortunately, the keyboard screen is still displayed in this new fragment and I want it to be hidden/disappear.

I have tried the following in onCreateView(..), inside on setOnClickListener button, in the fragment that displays the TextInputEditText view.

Snippet:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //send to the backend,when response come back, then insert
                Fragment fragment = null;
                Class fragmentClass = HashHomeFragment.class;

                try {
                    fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("hash_message", "thisstorehaslotsofdiscounts");
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.hash_container, fragment, "Home").commit();

                //hide keyboard
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);

            }
        });
```

But when android goes to the fragment, the keyboard is still present--the code doesn't work!

Can someone please help me figure out where and what code I need to hide the keyboard when I move from one fragment to another ? ...

Answer (score 1):

```
public void hideKeyboard() {

    View view = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().
                getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (imm != null) {
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: nice and easy answer

Answer (score 0):

```
  //hide keyboard
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("hash_message", "thisstorehaslotsofdiscounts");
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.hash_container, fragment, "Home").commit();
```

Reversing seems to do the trick. I forgot that when I call the very last fragmentManger command, the current fragment is in the process of being destroyed and the current view is not pointing to what I think it is. 
It makes much more sense to hide the keyboard with the current view intact, and then switch fragment!

Comment: I think, it is obvious. Hide the keyboard first, only then switch to another fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must clear focus of the EditText before hiding the keyboard. Try this function:

```
private void hideKeyboard(Context context) {
    if (context == null || !(context instanceof Activity) || ((Activity) context).getCurrentFocus() == null) {
        return;
    }
    View view = ((Activity) context).getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        view.clearFocus();
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (inputManager != null) {
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;

InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)
                              getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 

inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                                 InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

I put this right after the onClick(View v) event for all the buttons.

The keyboard hides when you click the button.
hope this helps...